# Is a stopped Ito-integral intergrable if the Ito integrand is only square-integrable on an open interval?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Assume a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\in[0;T)}, \mathbb P)$ with an $\mathbb R^n$-valued Brownian motion $\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T)}$ and the filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\in[0;T)}$ being the filtration generated by the Brownian motion, augmented by the nullsets.

Assume an $\mathbb R^n$-valued, progressively measurable stochastic process $\{Z_t\}_{t\in[0;T)}$ with the property
$$
\mathbb E\bigg( \int_0^t \Vert Z_t \Vert^2 \mathrm dt \bigg) < \infty
$$
for all $t \in [0;T)$, but possibly
$$
\mathbb E\bigg( \int_0^T \Vert Z_t \Vert^2 \mathrm dt \bigg) = \infty
$$

Assume a stopping time $\tau \colon \Omega \to [0;T)$.

I want to prove (but I don't know whether it's true...)
$$
\mathbb E\bigg( \int_0^\tau Z_t \mathrm dW_t \bigg) = 0.
$$
I think this can be reduced to a proof of the statement
$$
\mathbb E\bigg( \Big| \int_0^\tau Z_t \mathrm dW_t \Big| \bigg) < \infty
$$
because then I could use the dominated convergence theorem with the sequence $1_{\{\tau \le T - 1/n\}} \cdot \int_0^\tau Z_t \mathrm dW_t$.

But how to obtain this integrability property? Or is it even wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The question has been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384008/is-a-stopped-ito-integral-integrable-if-the-ito-integrand-is-only-square-integra